# Formatting seconds and minutes

Tags: java, time, format

I need to format seconds and minutes from milliseconds. I am using countdownTimer. does anyone have sugestions? I looked at joda time. But all i need is a format so i have 1:05 and not 1:5. thanks

```
private void walk() {
    new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            lapCounter++;
            lapNumber.setText("Lap Number: " + lapCounter);
            run();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            text.setText("Time left:" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Have you already looked into SimpleNumberFormat?  Alternatively you can always append a '0' to the left of your integer if it is less than 10.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will meet your entire needs, but it might be worth a look [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could do it using the standard Date formatting classes, but that might be a bit heavy-weight. I would just use the String.format method. For example:

```
int minutes = time / (60 * 1000);
int seconds = (time / 1000) % 60;
String str = String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: Great! that was exactly what i looking for! im not sure i understand the "%d:%02d" I tried this on my own and didnt get it right. Thanks!

Comment: % signals a replacement, 0 means zero-pad the number, 2 means make the width 2, and d means display as a decimal number. Here's the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 10):

A real lazy way of doing this as long as you know you won't have more than 60 minutes is to just make a date and use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
     dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
     Date date = new Date(millisUntilFinished);
     text.setText("Time left:" + dateFormat.format(date));
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! I like that you mentioned need to set `dateFormat.setTimeZone` to GMT. It's important.

Answer (score 7):

i'd use

```
org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(millisUntilFinished, "mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Apache Commons StopWatch class. The default output of it's toString method is ISO8601-like, hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds.

[Example of Apache StopWatch](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/org.apache.commons.logging/StopWatchgetTime.htm)